# show one list inside another one list of Resful api.

Tags: c#, linq

I have on restful api that returns me a list of picture and a list of comments but i cant see the list of comment, my service just returns a list empty.

This is the return of my  get

```
api/getjoin/{id:int}

{
    "idPicture": 1,
    "iduser": 15,
    "picture": "adress image",
    "comments": [],
    "likes": [],
    "users": null
  },
```

I would like to show my array of comments and my amount of likes. Like this

```
{
    "idPicture": 1,
    "iduser": 15,
    "picture": "adress image",
    "comments": {
                  "idcomment":1,
                   "comment": bla bla bla;
                },
                {
                  "idcomment":2,
                   "comment": bla bla bla;
                },
                {
                  "idcomment":3,
                   "comment": bla bla bla;
                },

    "likes": {
                  "amount":3;
                },
    "users": null
  },
```

This is my get class in c#

```
// GET api/getallpictures by user
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/getallpictures/{id:int}")]
        public List<pictures> Getallpictures(int id)
        {
            List<pictures> pictureList = new List<pictures>();
            List<comments> comemnts = new List<comments>();
            List<likes> listlikes = new List<likes>();
            var pic = from pictures in dc.pictures
                       where pictures.iduser == id
                      select pictures;
            foreach (var item in pic)
            {
                pictures pc = new pictures();
                pc.iduser = item.iduser;
                pc.idPicture = item.idPicture;
                pc.picture = item.picture;
                pictureList.Add(pc);

            };
            return pictureList;

        }
```

This is my model class

```
public class pictures { 
                       public int? idPicture { get; set; } 
                       public string iduser { get; set; } 
                       public string picture { get; set; } 
                   } 

public class comments { 
                       public int? idcomments { get; set; } 
                       public string idPicture { get; set; }
                       public string comment { get; set; } 
                      } 
public class likes { 
                    public int? idlikes { get; set; } 
                    public string idPicture { get; set; } 
                    public string amount { get; set; } 
                   }
```

Comment: You want to see comments list IN picture as response, but your picture class DOES NOT have comment list. See the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to update the pictures class like so.

```
    public class pictures
    {
        public int? idPicture { get; set; }
        public string iduser { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public List<comments> comments { get; set; }
        public List<likes> likes { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the pictures class has a relation with comments and likes.
And now in your foreach loop you can do the following for example

```
        foreach (var item in pictureList)
        {
            pictures pc = new pictures();
            //...

            pc.comments = new List<comments>();
            //linq to get comments here
            pc.comments.Add(new comments());

            pc.likes = new List<likes>();
            //linq to get likes
            pc.likes.Add(new likes());

            pictureList.Add(pc);
        };
```

Which adds the data to the object.

Comment: Works fine.. Thank you so much.